# Unable to save Tensorflow model due to custom metric

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have set some callbacks in place in order to save my Tensorflow model, however it fails with the following warning:

```
WARNING:Can save best model only with val_Multi_MeanIoU available, skipping.
```

I pass the following to callbacks to `model.fit`:

```
monitor_mode = "max"
es_patience = 8
log_dir = "/some/directory/"
monitor_metric = "val_" + met.__name__
cllbs = [
    #ks.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = "val_loss", factor = 0.2,
    #                               patience = 5, min_lr = 0.001),
    ks.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = monitor_metric, mode = monitor_mode, \
                               patience = es_patience, verbose = 1),
    ks.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(cptdir, \
                                              "Epoch.{epoch:02d}.hdf5"), \
                                 monitor = monitor_metric, \
                                 mode = monitor_mode, \
                                 save_best_only = True, \
                                 save_freq = 1),
    ks.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir, histogram_freq = 5)
    ]
```

`cb_metric` is an argument I pass to the Python script and it is set to `None`.

The metric is defined as:

```
class MulticlassMeanIoU(tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU):
    def __init__(self,
                 y_true = None,
                 y_pred = None,
                 num_classes = None,
                 name = "MultiMeanIoU",
                 dtype = None):
        super(MulticlassMeanIoU, self).__init__(num_classes = num_classes,
                                             name = name, dtype = dtype)
        self.__name__ = name

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight = None):
        y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis = -1)
        return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

met = MulticlassMeanIoU(num_classes = N_CLASSES)
metrix = [met, "sparse_categorical_accuracy"]
model.compile.(..., metrics = metrix)
```

where `N_CLASSES` is the number of classes for my semantic segmentation model.

Initially, I monitored different metrics in different callbacks, but I read an answer to another question stating the metric mus always have the same name. I fixed that, but it is still not working.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: For some reason. tf.Keras inserts an underscore in the metric name. I added this underscore to where I defined the metric name. Now the names match but it still fails with the same error.

When I do this:

```
hist = model.fit(...)
with open("/some/path/Hist.txt", "w") as f:
            for key in hist.history:
                f.write(key)
                f.write("\n")
```

I get the following contents in the .txt file:

```
loss
Multi_MeanIoU
sparse_categorical_accuracy
val_loss
val_Multi_MeanIoU
val_sparse_categorical_accuracy
```

Comment: The name of the metric is probably val_MultiMeanIoU, correct it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Do I have to name the metric like that? Because I set the variable ```monitor_metric``` to ```"val_MultiMeanIoU"``` by adding ```"val_"``` to the metric name. I assumed the prefix is only added to specify whether I want to track the performance on the training or on the validation data?

Comment: The name of the metric by default is MultiMeanIoU, not sure where Multi_MeanIoU is coming from.

Comment: Neither am I; it looks like Keras/Tensorflow came up with this underscore in the name all by itself... this way of writing the metric name is not in my code